# Videojs Display current time through out video

Tags: javascript, video

I'm struggling to see how to display the current video position of  video and update the timer.

I want the current video time to continuously display in the div #time_count
The code I have  is

```
            <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video.js"></script>

            <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
              poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
              data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
             <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            </video>
            <div id="time_count"></div>
            <script>

            (function() {
                var myPlayer;
                var myTextArea = document.getElementById('time_count');

                videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){

                    myPlayer = this;
                    myPlayer.play();
                    myPlayer.on("progress", onProgress);
                });


                function onProgress() {
                console.log(myPlayer.duration());
                  myTextArea.innerHTML = myPlayer.currentTime();
                  return false;
                }

            })();
            </script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just after I add the comment I found the solution I should use timeupdate,    

so it would be 
                    myPlayer.on("timeupdate", onProgress);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after I added the comment I found the solution I should use timeupdate, so it would be myPlayer.on("timeupdate", onProgress)